# UIImage Not Changing

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I know the code is correct and the battery level received is also the correct value. But my UIImage does not update. Any ideas?

```
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BATTERY_UUID]]) {

        int16_t BatteryData = 0;
        [characteristic.value getBytes:&BatteryData length:sizeof(BatteryData)];
        _SRBattery.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", BatteryData];

        if ((int)BatteryData <40) {_BatteryImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Status-battery-low-icon.png"];NSLog(@"<40 %d", (int)BatteryData);}
        if ((int)BatteryData >=40 & (int)BatteryData <60) {_BatteryImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Status-battery-60-icon.png"];NSLog(@">=40 <60 %d", (int)BatteryData);}
        if ((int)BatteryData >=60 & (int)BatteryData <80) {_BatteryImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Status-battery-80-icon.png"];NSLog(@">=60 <80 %d", (int)BatteryData);}
        if ((int)BatteryData >=80 & (int)BatteryData <95) {_BatteryImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Status-battery-80-icon.png"];NSLog(@">=80 <95 %d", (int)BatteryData);}
        if ((int)BatteryData >=95) {_BatteryImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Status-battery-100-icon.png"];NSLog(@">=95 %d", (int)BatteryData);}
    }
```

Comment: maybe you can use after thats 
   [ self.view setNeedsDisplay ];

Comment: The logic works with & and with &&, its not the logic which is an issue. The UIImage does not change. The NSLog shows that the logic works.

Comment: is it on main thread?

Comment: ? Sorry I do not understand "is it on main thread"...